# date and time format and into one string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've `date = 12/06/2017(mm/dd/yyyy)` and time  `02:11`.

The code is as follows

```
 var date=$('#datepicker_reservation').val();// returns date

 var time=$('#timePicker_reservation').val();// returns time
```

Help ...Thanks in advance

Comment: You can concatenate the two strings with a space `var datetime = date + ' ' + time`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var rdate = $('#datepicker_reservation').val().split('/');
var rtime = $('#timePicker_reservation').val();
var newdt = rdate[2]+'-'+rdate[0]+'-'+rdate[1]+' '+rtime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fnclick()
{
 var date= "12-04-2017"

 var time=" 05:12 PM"
var date =  formatDate(new Date(date + time))
     $("#div1").html('').html(date);
     alert(date);
}

function formatDate(date) {
    try {
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return date.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

</div>

<button onclick='fnclick()'> show me date</button>
```